# SQL Server - Compare months of current year with months of the previous year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to compare the months of the current year (2020) with the same months of the previous year (2019). I have to calculate the delta in percent, but that's a task I can solve on my own.

I tried joining the table with itself. The columns that I need are `Month_Year`, `Revenue 1` and `Revenue 2`.

My problem is that the revenues aren't correct.

This is my query so far:

```
select 
    a.Month_Year 'Month_Year1'
    ,b.Month_Year 'Month_Year2'
    ,sum(a.[Revenue1]) 'Revenue1'
    ,sum(a.[Revenue2]) 'Revenue2'
    ,sum(b.[Revenue1_last_year]) 'Revenue1_last_year'
    ,sum(b.[Revenue2_last_year]) 'Revenue2_last_year'
from 
    #a
join
    #b on a.Month = b.Month and a.Year= b.Year -1
group by
    a.Month_Year, b.Month_Year
order by
    [Month_Year1] asc, [Month_Year2] asc
```

In my output, the months are correct, but my revenue seems to just add up random numbers.

Comment: **Impossible** to answer unless you provide some **sample data** that shows / illustrates the "add up random numbers" claim ....

Comment: You say you are joining the table to itself, but the `join` has two different tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select only the years in question, then group by months and sum up conditionally per year:

```
select 
  month,
  sum(case when year = year(getdate()) then revenue1 end) as r1_this_year,
  sum(case when year = year(getdate()) then revenue2 end) as r2_this_year,
  sum(case when year < year(getdate()) then revenue1 end) as r1_last_year,
  sum(case when year < year(getdate()) then revenue2 end) as r2_last_year
from mytable
where year in (year(getdate()), year(getdate()) - 1)
group by month
order by month;
```

If you want this until the current month only (i.e. show January till March now, but not April till December), add `and month <= month(getdate())` to the where clause.

As to your own query: You join every #a row with every #b row where month and year match. So with, say, 10 #a rows for January 2019 and 5 #b rows for January 2020, you produce 10 x 5 = 50 rows. Then you aggregate and sum things up and get multiples of the real values (because 1+2 is different from 1+1+1+2+2+2 for instance :-).

Answer (score 1):

If the data is in one table and you have table for every month, you can use `lag()`:

```
select a.Month_Year as month_year
       sum(a.Revenue1)  as Revenue1,
       sum(a.Revenue2) as Revenue2,
       lag(sum(a.Revenue1), 12) over (order by a.Month_Year) as Revenue1_ly,
       lag(sum(a.Revenue2)) over (order by a.Month_Year) as Revenue2_ly
from #a
group by a.Month_Year;
```

Comment: thank you! this might not have solved the problem in first try, but gave me a better understanding.